# d3 v3 not starting transition on g elements

Tags: d3.js, transition, translate-animation

problem: moved from d3v2 to d3v3 and transitions stopped working.

the idea is to have some boxes appear on the screen, such that the new ones come sliding from the left. when elements change location, they should move to the new location.

I checked the migration documentation at (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Upgrading-to-3.0). Code looks like this:

```
elements = svg.selectAll(".element").data( d3.values(@mystuff.elements), (x)->x.id )
elements.enter().insert("g",".box")
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "element")
            .attr("id", (d)-> "elem_#{d.id}" )
            .attr("transform", @element_start_position )
            .call(@drag_action)
            .on( "click", @on_element_click )

elements.transition().duration(750)
        .each("start", () -> console.debug("start transition") )
        .attr("transform",  (d)-> @element_final_position )
```

`element_start_position: (d)->"translate(0,#{d.y})"`

`element_final_position: (d)->"translate(#{d.x},#{d.y})"`

what I see is that the `enter()` works, but the `update` doesn't. the `console.debug()` doesn't get called and the elements are left in their starting location.

*help me Stack Overflow, you're my only hope...*

Comment: your last sentence, I remember I said that to myself a few times.

Answer (score 1):

```
.attr("transform",  (d)-> @element_final_position )
```

should either be this:

```
.attr("transform",  (d) => @element_final_position )
```

or more likely:

```
.attr("transform",  @element_final_position )
```

Comment: but why doesn't the "start" callback get called ?

Comment: So now the elements animate to the right position but the "start" callback still doesn't get called? That's bizarre. I have basically the same scenario working here: http://jsfiddle.net/B4W6g/, and "start" DOES trigger. Dunno what to tell ya... Sounds like maybe it's affected by some other factors that are not shown here(?).